# cucumber BDD selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

how to reuse a step definition from one class to multiple feature class? eg. login.feature
Scenario: it checks the login flow
Given: User logs in the home page
When:
Then:

again another feature class logout.feature
Scenario: it checks the logout flow
Given: User logs in the home page
When:
Then: User logs out from home page
We have step definition classes login want to use the Given step of login.java in logout.feature without rewriting it in logout.java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reuse a feature as the "Given" for another feature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812758/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-feature-as-the-given-for-another-feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the step in the logout.feature file, just write the step "Given: User logs in the home page" in the logout.feature file.
Cucumber will automatically link the step to the login.java file.

If you want to access the step in the logout.java file then call the function which is mapped to the required step.

```
@And("^I login in the home page$")
public void I_login_in_the_home_page(){
//login logic
}
```

For above eg you can call I_login_in_the_home_page() from logout.java file.