# Can we reuse a scenario in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am working in protractor-cucumber framework.In our requirement,one section is common in all part.Let say creating a post in 10 locations.So how can i reuse the scenario of creating post, so that it can be reuse in all locations.Do we have any way to reuse a scenario in cucumber.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reuse a feature as the "Given" for another feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812758/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-feature-as-the-given-for-another-feature)

Comment: As [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813061/1301972), you can reuse steps but not scenarios.

Comment: Create a step that does what the scenarios do - use that step as a Given to set up the scenarios.

Either that, or you make it a hook, and exclude it from the test of that functionality