# Cucumber - Same feature for multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm using cucumber features for my rails application.

I want to use some features in more than one pages (the only thing that will change is the visited page).

Is there a way to accomplish this without duplicating the feature (**something like** setting the page as a variable or something and repeat the feature execution for each value)?

Comment: Have a look at option 4 in this page (which might be generally useful for you - http://makandracards.com/makandra/18905-how-to-not-repeat-yourself-in-cucumber-scenarios) - is it the sort of thing you mean?  (it's where you make a sort of 'table' of values in your feature)

Comment: If I understand what you're looking for, does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646696/how-to-use-common-shared-blocks-between-cucumber-features answer your question?