# Given/When/Then deprecated in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm getting the following warning with this code:

```
WARNING: Using 'Given/When/Then' in step definitions is deprecated, use 'step' to call other steps instead
```

How can I correct this?

Code:

```
Feature: Viewing tickets
 In order to view the tickets for a project
 As a user
 I want to see them on that project's page

Background:
 Given there is a project called "TextMate 2"
 And that project has a ticket:
 | title           | description                   |
 |  Make it shiny! | Gradients! Starbursts! Oh my! |
 And there is a project called "Internet Explorer"
 And that project has a ticket:
 | title                | description   |
 | Standards compliance | Isn't a joke. |
 And I am on the homepage

Scenario: Viewing tickets for a given project
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should see "Make it shiny!"
  And I should not see "Standards compliance"
  When I follow "Make it shiny!"
  Then I should see "Make it shiny" within "#ticket h2"
  And I should see "Gradients! Starbursts! Oh my!"

  When I am on the homepage
  And I follow "Internet Explorer"
  Then I should see "Standards compliance"
  And I should not see "Make it shiny!"
  When I follow "Standards compliance"
  Then I should see "Standards compliance" within "#ticket h2"
  And I should see "Isn't a joke.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will be due to the step definitions rather than the feature file code - could you post up your step definition code?

Comment: You can use the step method for a single step or steps for multiple steps. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918066/reuse-cucumber-steps/8395715#8395715

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere in step definitions you're using the following construction:

```
Then "a file named '#{want_file}' should exist"
```

instead you should use

```
step("a file named '#{want_file}' should exist")
```

or (preferred I think) - avoid calling one step from another at all. It is better to refactor definitions and extract common part into separate class or method.

Comment: if the prefix is `step`, how will cucumber know if I'm referring to a `given` `when` or `then`?

Answer (score 1):

replace this (features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb, line 35-37):

```
When /^(.*) within (.*[^:])$/ do |step, parent|
  with_scope(parent) { When step }
end
```

with something like this:

```
When /^(.*) within (.*[^:])$/ do |the_step, parent|
  with_scope(parent) { step the_step }
end
```

worked for me !