# Reuse features in Cucumber

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing, cucumber

I want to test an app using Cucumber and Gherkin. Now I have the login part and then I have a form. Now I want to test this form for validation, but there are many combinations that I can do with valid and invalid data there and so a big number of tests.

Is there a way to reuse the feature of login so I do not have to insert the code in each new feature of validation??
I read this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918066/reuse-cucumber-steps), but it doesnt work for me.

I do it like this:

```html
 Scenario: Test1
   Given I have already logged in
   step login 
   step put username
   step put password
       
   When I put validation data

   Then ...
```

Where each one of teh steps is astep definition of login feature and works. It gives me parse erros this way, maybe because the solution is for Ruby and I am using javascript?
How can I reuse the login feature??

Comment: You can. Try hook in cucumber to run it before or after any feature or scenario please refer this http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-hooks/

Comment: https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline here i found the answer